# Get shared element transitions inside the recylerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-transitions

I need a shared transition in recylerview to an activity but getting the error "Application cannot be cast to Activity" tried passing Adpater.this/this/Adapter.class but nothing is working

```
 ViewCompat.setTransitionName(holder.imageView, photo.getId());
    holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Fullscreen.class);

            ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation((MainActivity) mContext, holder.imageView, ViewCompat.getTransitionName(holder.imageView));
            mContext.startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
        }

    });

}
```

Comment: ((Activity)context).startActivity(intent, optionsCompat.toBundle());

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Answer (score 0):

problem is in `(MainActivity)mContext` line. Your `mContext` is `Application` type but you try to cast it to `Activity` type, thats why it throws `ClassCastException`. Declare your field as `Activity mContext;` instead of `Context mContext;` and IDE will show you that you init your `mContext` variable with wrong type object.

Comment: But i cannot use activity there because the Adapter recives the context as paramter from fragments.